# How to make %random% show up a negative result?

Tags: batch-file, random

I'm making a game where there are stocks, and I want them to be able to go negative, I know how to limit the positive random numbers, but how do I get the `%random%` to make a negative value? And, is making the `%random%` generate negative numbers even possible?

Comment: `set num=-%random%`? From `set /?` help: "%RANDOM% generate a random decimal number between 0 and 32767"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce a random number in the range `minrand` to `maxrand` use

```
SET /a selection=%RANDOM% %% (%maxrand% - %minrand% + 1) + %minrand%
```

Here's a sampler : change the values assigned to  `minrand` and `maxrand` to test:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /a minrand=-3
SET /a maxrand=3

FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,20) DO CALL :genshow
GOTO :eof

:genshow
SET /a selection=%RANDOM% %% (%maxrand% - %minrand% + 1) + %minrand%
ECHO %selection%
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

Just subtract the random number from 0.

```
set /a negative_random=0-%random%
```

Comment: Ok, this works and can be ranged by doing this: `set /a NUM=0-%random% %%NUMBER -1` but can it include positive numbers?

Comment: just `negative_random=-%random%` is enough because unary minus exists in set expression

Comment: ... or multiply it by -1: `set /A negRan=-1*%random%`, or take its 2's complement: `set /A negRan=~%random%+1`  **`;-)`**

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the range you want. If [-16384, 16383] is enough for you, use this

```
set /a num=%random%-16384
```

Otherwise if you need random values in the range [a, b] then use this

```
set /a num=%random% %%(b-a+1) + a
```

For example to get values from -10 to 20, use this

```
set /a num=%random% %%31 - 10
```